# Does yum update uninstall and install the dependencies?

Tags: linux, yum

If the dependencies of the two different versions of RPM are same, would yum update remove and install dependencies too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple answer is `no`. The YUM updater is smart enough to determine dependencies in the installed package manifest. For example:

Say you have two packages:

`Package_1.0.rpm`

`Dependent_package_1.0.rpm`

And you want to upgrade `Package_1.0.rpm` to `Package_2.0.rpm` but the dependency is still `Dependent_package_1.0.rpm`, YUM will do the following:

`yum update Package_1.0`

`Would you like to install Package_2.0?`

It's smart enough to know that `Dependent_package_1.0` satisfies the dependencies for *both* `Package_1.0` and `Package_2.0`